# Is the inverse of a matrix of smooth functions a matrix of smooth functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth functions, where $1\leq i,j \leq n$. Suppose for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $M_x=(f_{ij}(x))$ forms a nonsingular matrix, is it true that $M_x^{-1}$ gives a matrix of smooth functions (with respect to $x$)?

Comment: The map $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ is $C^\infty$ on the set of non-singular matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The determinant is a polynomial, and when you plug in smooth functions, what you obtain is another smooth function $g$. You are assuming that the determinant has no zeroes, so $1/g$ is also smooth. Now the inverse of a matrix is the product of $1/g$ with the [adjugate matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), whose entries are smooth by similar arguments.